# можно ли как-то у унаследованного класса расширить метод его прототипа

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть класс `Blog` со следующем методом

```
createEventListener() {

    this.$searchLink.addEventListener('click', this.search.bind(this));
    this.$searchText.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) this.$searchLink.click();
    })
}
```

И есть класс `AdminBlog`(подкласс) от `Blog`, у него также есть метод createEventListener.

Мне нужно чтобы вызывался свой метод и прототипа.
Можно ли так сделать или всё таки переименовать метод

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать метод прототипа с установленным контекстом

```
createEventListener() {
    Blog.prototype.createEventListener.call(this);

    this.$searchLink.addEventListener('click', this.search.bind(this));
    this.$searchText.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) this.$searchLink.click();
    });
}
```

В ES6 все гораздо проще.

```
createEventListener() {
    super.createEventListener();

    this.$searchLink.addEventListener('click', this.search.bind(this));
    this.$searchText.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) this.$searchLink.click();
    });
}
```